# Swift: UIAlertController not presented within dispatch_async

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I have a setting where I used UIAlertController to show progress of a task till the task has some status to return.

The code looks like this

```
class AlertVCDemo: UIViewController {
    let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Search",
                                message: "Searching....", preferredStyle: 
                                UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
            case .Default:
                print("default")

            case .Cancel:
                print("cancel")

            case .Destructive:
                print("destructive")
            }
        }))
    }

    func showAlertVC() {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.presentViewController(self.alertVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
    }

    @IBAction func searchButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
        showAlertVC()
        // Now do the real search that will take a while,
        // depending on the result change the message of the alert VC
    }
}
```

Somehow I see that the alert view controller is not shown in the main thread. The search logic completes eventually. I am using iOS 9.3. I did thorough research before asking this question and none of the solutions suggested on similar threads helped. Not sure why dispatch_async doesn't present the alert VC when search is still happening.

Even if I have the dispatch_async not in a method, things don't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@IBAction func searchButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    showAlertVC()
    // Now do the real search that will take a while,
    // depending on the result change the message of the alert VC
}
```

is called in the main thread. So i guess your "search code" is blocking the UI thread.
Try something like this

```
@IBAction func searchButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    showAlertVC()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        // put your search code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, hard to believe the other way - showAlertVC in dispatch_async won't work when most online solutions suggested doing it that way. I will go through dispatch_async workings again to solidify my understanding (which sometimes puzzles me in situations like this)

Answer (score 0):

Check for `UIViewController`'s `presentedViewController` property. It should be nil. If it is not nil, `presentViewController` method wont work.

Comment: Checked this and can confirm that this property is nil.